# How to Set the Font Weight in Apps Script - Google Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, styling, google-apps-script-addon

Looking through the Document Reference (found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document)), I was unable to find any way to set the font weight of a Paragraph element.

Is it even possible to do so?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that this official document is useful. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setattributesattributes If this didn't resolve your issue, please tell us.

Comment: @Tanaike: I've already looked into this and there is nothing under "DocumentApp.Attribute" that could be used to alter the font weight. You can change the font size, but this is not the same thing. It is possible to make the text bold, which although this is technically changing the font weight, it does not allow for full control over the change.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide your current script and a sample Document for replicating the issue? At that time, please include the input and output you want. By this, it will help users including me think of the issue and solution. Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Answer (score 2):

To adjust between normal and bold weights:

1. Use [`setAttributes`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setattributesattributes) and set `DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD` to `true` or `false` (as @Tanaike alluded above).
2. Use [`setBold(bold)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setboldbold) or [`setBold(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, bold)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setboldstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-bold).

**To set weights other than normal and bold** for fonts that include additional weights (e.g. the medium weight of Alegreya Sans) there's an apparently undocumented method: use the [`setFontFamily(fontFamilyName)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setfontfamilyfontfamilyname) or [`setFontFamily(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, fontFamilyName)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setfontfamilystartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-fontfamilyname) method and append a semicolon and the numeric [CSS font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) to the font family string, like this:

```js
someElement.setFontFamily('Alegreya Sans;500')
```

Comment: I confirm that your last method works — thanks a lot, crazy that this is not documented. There is also apparently `setFontFamilyAndWeight(fontFamily, fontWeight)` but I did not manage to make it work ([source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#setfontfamilyandweightfontfamily,-fontweight)).